# react with redux, event handler name

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am looking at this [source code](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/async/src/components/Picker.js).

```
render() {
    const { value, onChange, options } = this.props

    return (
      <span>
        <h1>{value}</h1>
        <select onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
                value={value}>
          {options.map(option =>
            <option value={option} key={option}>
              {option}
            </option>)
          }
        </select>
      </span>
    )
  }
```

my question is, why the event handler is `onChange`? I think the standard html attribute is `onchange`. and unfortunately, I cannot find any react document about the event handler names

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event is defined as onChange in ReactJS:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

You have some examples of use in ReactJS documentation website:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, HTML attributes are case insensitive, so `onchange`, `onChange` and `ONCHANGE` are all equivalent in HTML.

However, JSX is not HTML. In React, case is important, so `onChange` it must be.

The `select` element in React also differs in other ways from the select element in HTML. For instance, `value` is defined on the `select` element, making the `selected` attribute on the `option` element obsolete.